# Continuous Queries vs Storing and Recalling Data

Tags: php

I would like to know which of the following methods would be best to use on a website, and a brief explanation on why. Please assume that `$user` is `$user = new User()` throughout this question

1. Whether to store my data returned from a database query, as an array (`$user_data`) and then convert into an object for further referencing. (eg to get the user's name `$user->data->name`). Please note I also intend to add further to the user class for data such as permissions.
2. To keep querying the database each time I want a bit of new bit of data, so use `$user->data("name")`.

I am new to object orientated php and couldn't find any tips on this and may also have made some mistakes in my query ideas.

Comment: Not sure what database you're using, but my policy has always been to use as few queries as possible. I think it's more efficient to store the data in memory rather than fetching it from the database every time, but then I suppose it depends on how often you will need to access the data and how much data you will be storing in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you want to minimise your database queries, so once you have pulled your user into memory keep him there.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I thought it would be something like that but wanted to check to make sure my code would work best and be suitable with classes.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you query the database, you are using resources.  Each query takes time.  If the data you are gathering is not going to change rapidly, it is better to query as much as you'll need, store it, and then call upon it as needed.  The goal is to reduce the number of calls to the db (which by the way, is the whole purpose of caching).